# Ionic Never loads api data

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

I have set an ionic loading screen to run while the app is loading the data from an API endpoint I am using.  The issue is that the ionic app never dismisses the loading screen and displays the data.  When I check the url outside of the ionic call the json data is loaded already.  I am unsure of why it is never being called in the application.

Below is the page that calls the data:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RestService } from '../../providers/rest-service/rest-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-all-patients',
  templateUrl: 'all-patients.html',
  providers: [RestService]
})
export class AllPatientsPage {
  data: any;
  loading: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public restService: RestService, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {

    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait while data is loading'
    });
    this.getdata();
  }

  getdata() {
    this.loading.present();
    this.restService.getJsonData().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.data=result.data.children;
        console.log("Success: " + this.data);
      },
      err => {
        console.error("Error : " + err);
      },
      () => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        console.log('getData completed');
     }
   );
 }
}
```

Below is the RestServices.ts:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the RestServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/

@Injectable()
export class RestService {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello RestServiceProvider Provider');
  }

  getJsonData() {
    // return Promise.resolve(this.data);

     return this.http.get('url_is_here').map(res => res.json());
   }

}
```

Does anyone know what may be causing this issue, if it is an issue of the calling the json data itself, or if it is an issue dismissing the loading screen?  I am confused because the application runs without any error messages.

Comment: What happens if you place `this.loading.dismiss();` within `subscribe` first two parameters (fetch function and error handler)? Does any of them get called? (success or error)?

Comment: @Alexei it is running on the `err => {` call

Comment: So, you should make sure you dismiss thee loader on both "normal" path and error path. `Sajeetharan` indicated a pattern that should work without issues.

Answer (score 2):

Your getData should be something like this,

```
getdata() {
    this.loading.present();
    this.restService.getJsonData().subscribe(
    result => {
        this.data=result.data.children;
        console.log("Success: " + this.data);
        this.loading.dismiss();
    },
    err => {
        console.error("Error : " + err);
        this.loading.dismiss();
    } 
);
```

Comment: I have made this change, but `err` is still being called.  Is this automatically and error with the `getJsonData()` method, or could it be how the data is called in the html code that is causing an error here as well?